# How do I accept a non-csv input for my machine learning model?

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-mining, data-science

Language: Python.
I have created a model and saved it with joblib. Now I want to load it to make predictions for new data---but the data is in a form of string(numerical in value but the features are a single line separated by "," instead of in columns as one big dataframe) Can I do that? I know I can send in single inputs and get a single prediction but I'm not sure how to do it.

I used 
https://machinelearningmastery.com/save-load-machine-learning-models-python-scikit-learn/
as reference but I'm not too clear about the last bit (loading the model)

```
# Splitting the dataset into the Training set and Test set
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.25, random_state = 0)

# Feature Scaling
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc = StandardScaler()
X_train = sc.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = sc.transform(X_test)

# Fitting K-NN to the Training set
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
classifier = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors = 5, metric = 'minkowski', p = 2)
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Predicting the Test set results
y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)

# save the model to disk
filename = 'test_model.sav'
joblib.dump(classifier, filename)

loaded_model = joblib.load(filename)
result = loaded_model.score(X_test, y_test)
print(result)
```

*I did not post the data preprocessing part of the code

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: What does the input string look like?

Comment: what is test_model.sav data format look like?

Comment: @akilat90  for simplicity's sake let's say if my model were to predict whether a human is an adult or a child, my features should be weight, height, age so the string that I want to input could be something like:
34,144,13

Comment: @be_good_do_good it should return an output result in binary form of 0 or 1

Comment: Just parse the string yourself and create an array out of it?

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is about how to load the input vector `X_test` from a string input, you can use [np.fromstring](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.fromstring.html):

```
input_string = '34,144,13'
X_test=np.fromstring(input_string, dtype=int, sep=',')
```

To get the model's prediction for the above `X_test`, you can use:

```
loaded_model = joblib.load(filename)
prediction= loaded_model.predict(X_test)
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a try